# Closing unanswered questions

Tags: discussion

Just because noone can answer them doesnt mean they should be closed. Why do this when you can just be patient? Isnt this better in the long run?

Comment: Do you have an example you could link to?

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17000/maximum-sustainable-employment-vs-full-employment-beginner

Answer (score 1):

1) The specific answer was closed as "unclear what is asked", not because "nobody can answer".

2) The answer was subsequently deleted automatically by the SE machinery, see 
https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba

for the reason why. This is SE policy across all sites.

Comment: I fail to see how the question is unclear. If nobody can answer the question, it should not be automatically marked unclear. The question cannot be further simplified, it is literally a definition.

Comment: It is not an issue whether the question _is_ "unclear". It is an issue whether enough members of this community _think_ that this is so ("rightly" or "wrongly"). Apart from that, your edit that came after the question was closed made the question indeed a very specific requirement for a definition, and so certainly answerable. But it appears it didn't attract anew any interest, and it was subsequently deleted by the SE system automatically.

Comment: In any case, I have nominated your question for re-opening.

Comment: ah i understand the processes better, thanks